# I have to track the flow of execution in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I know how to debug in eclipse, but I want to know an effective way of finding the flow of execution from a method.

E g:

```
class A
{
    method S()
    {}

    method S1()
    {
        B.SS()
    }

    method S2() 
    {
        A.S1()
    }
}

class B
{
    method SS()
    {    
        A.S()
    }

    method SS1()
    {
        B.SS2()
    }

    method SS2()
    {
        A.S2()
    }
}
```

Given these two classes, how can I trace the flow of the methods from `A.S2()` to `A.S()` other than debugging?

Comment: F5 into debug = "Step into"

Comment: I just gave a flow. But I m asking in real time scenario. Just gave an example so as to clear with the concept rather giving bunch of codes and making it complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CTRL + ALT + H shows you the call hierarchy for a method. Perhaps that's what you wanted.

So it you highlight a method and click CTRL + ALT + H, it shows, in the Call Hierarchy window, all the methods the call that method, and for each of those methods, all the methods that call them, and so on ...

Comment: If this reply answers your question, please mark it as the answer.  Additionally, you can do what Antonio Balduzzi suggested and run on debug mode by placing a breakpoint somewhere in the code and step through the code by pressing 'F5'. You can start the application on debug mode by selecting the debug button on the tool bar, or you can right-click the class that contains the main method and select "Debug As --> Java application"

Answer (score -1):

When function A calls function B. Press CTRL, then use mouse to left-click on the called-function B, then the cursor would move to the definition of function B.  By the same continuous way, you can get deeper and deeper, at last to the final function being called.

Comment: And do what afterwards? This doesn't answer the question at all. Your suggestion is incomplete.